# How to rotate text with XLConnect R package?

Tags: r, xlconnect

I am using the XLConnect R package. I would like to make cells with rotated text in excel, using this package. but I can't do it. Could you help me with that?

Answer (score 1):

That's not currently a feature of the `XLConnect` library. From the documentation:

> XLConnect does not currently allow direct access to low-level
>   formatting options.

Having said that, they do provide a hack for cell formatting:

1. define some named cell styles in an Excel document (”Format” -
   >
   ”Styles” in pre-2007 Excel, ”Cell
   styles” on the default pane of Excel 2007 and on)
2. save the document to a file
3. then load this template in
   XLConnect
   and use the setCellStyle method to assign the predefined styles

That's your best bet.

Alternatively, some VBA code you could integrate into your scripts from the [MSDN community](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c603bc3c-0c17-405c-b8f2-239848624f95/rotate-text-in-cell?forum=exceldev) goes like this:

```
Sub SlantText()
Dim r As Range
Set r = Range("B9")
With r
    .Value = "Hello World"
    .Orientation = 90
End With
End Sub
```

where `.Orientation` is the rotation attribute you're looking for.